# Preview in Catalina doesn't allow automatic form filling?

Tags: macos, catalina, pdf, preview

Prior to Catalina (10.15) (at least in 10.14), you could click on a checkbox and it'd tick it (even if the PDF wasn't a fillable PDF). You could also click near a line and Preview would identify that there was a line there and insert a text object automatically.

Am I missing something, or were these features removed?

Answer (score 2):

I've confirmed that this feature was removed in Catalina.

For confirmation you can see on in the Preview User Guide from Apple.

If you [check the Mojave (10.14) version](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/fill-out-and-sign-pdf-forms-prvw35725/10.1/mac/10.14), it says "Click a field **or a line** in the form. **A text annotation box automatically appears.**".

If you switch over to [the Catalina (10.15) version](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/fill-out-and-sign-pdf-forms-prvw35725/11.0/mac/10.15), it now only says "Click a field in the form, then type your text.".

[image: Mojave Preview Guide Screenshot]

[image: Catalina Preview Guide Screenshot]